# Sending a request and receiving an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

When I send the form, I'll get the page.

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

How can I fix this so that when I click on the submit button I do not drop there and just update the page.

Secondly, and most importantly, after submitting the data in the form, I get an empty array, why? That is, after pressing the submit button, I drop it on the page I described at the top. `The page has expired due to inactivity`. after `backspace` if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then at the top of the page you can see this code.

```
Array
(
)
```

> Why is the array empty? And please tell me how to fix it.

Here's my template **contact.blade.php**

```
@extends ("default.layouts.layout")

@section("content")
<div style="display: flex;">
    <form method="post" action="{{ route ('contact') }}">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" >
        <label for="e-mail">E-mail adress</label>
        <input  name="e-mail" type="text">
        <label for="site">Site</label>
        <input name="site" type="text" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >

        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <button style="background-color:lightslategrey" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<style>
    input {
        display: flex;
    }
</style>
@endsection
```

Here's my Controller **ContactController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller
{




    public function show(Request $request){

        print_r($request->all());

        return view("default.contact",["title"=>"Contacts"]);
    }
}
```

Also route **web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get("/",["as"=>"home","uses"=>"Admin\IndexController@show"]);

Route::get("/about",["uses"=>"Admin\AboutController@show", "as"=>"about"]);

Route::match(["get","post"],"/contact",["uses"=>"Admin\ContactController@show","as"=>"contact"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the following error

> The page has expired due to inactivity.
>
> Please refresh and try again.

Add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to your form

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route ('contact') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue it that you have no CSRF token on your form. Laravel needs the CSRF token every time you perform a request otherwise it will just error out.

Add this to your form and see if it helps.

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```